# bash - check if string variable equals form feed

Tags: bash, pdftotext

I am new to bash, so this is likely simply answered, but my research has yet to garner me a solution. I am trying to write a simple bash script that checks if a pdf needs to be OCR'd. It uses the `pdftotext` executable distributed with Xpdf. If `pdftotext` doesn't output any text, then the PDF needs to be OCR'd. The problem is, if a PDF hasn't been OCR'd, `pdftotext` returns a Form Feed character (not simply an empty string). Try as I might, I can't get bash to compare the string returned from `pdftotext` with the form feed.

Here's my code:

```
pdf_txt=$(pdftotext -q -l 5 '/Path/to/pdf/test.pdf' -)
if [ "$pdf_txt" = "\f" ]
then
    echo 'needs ocr'
else
    echo "doesn't need ocr"
fi
```

Now, `test.pdf` has not been OCR'd. If I run this test in Python and use `repr()` I get `\x0c`, the character code for the form feed. But `echo`ing `$pdf_txt` in bash just prints the blank line.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

> ```
> "\f"
> ```

does not do what you think it does.  Use [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
$'\f'
```

Also,

```
pdf_txt="$(pdftotext -q -l 5 '/Path/to/pdf/test.pdf' -)"
```

Comment: Gah! I knew it was something simple. I just could find the right Google keywords to find it. Thank you. If I might ask a related question, what is the exact difference in meaning between the quoted `pdf_txt` var and the unquoted version?

Comment: The quotes retain all bytes generated, whereas leaving it unquoted can remove whitespace from the ends.

Comment: +1 For the Ansi-C quoting. For your second point though, I think that it is not necessary to quote command substitution in the right hand of the assignment, as it is not subject to word splitting or pathname expansion. E.g. you can do `a=$(ls -l *); echo "$a"`